# High Sierra: How to resize window taller than screen?

Tags: mac, high-sierra

I'm trying to capture a screenshot of a browser window, where the page content is quite tall.

In Sierra, I could drag the window down, and then resize from the top of the window (moving up). I could repeat this process until the window was tall enough to contain all of the page content, and then take a screenshot of the browser window.

In High Sierra, at the completion of any vertical resize operation that results in the window being taller than the active display, the window snaps to the size of the active display.

I've tried browser extensions that cause window resizing, and an AppleScript that tells the browser to resize. On a MacBook Pro and a 27" 5K iMac. To no avail.

Does anyone have a solution? In the meantime, I guess I'll be stitching multiple screenshots together.

Comment: How about extensions that can take "full page screenshots"? If you search Firefox or Chrome extensions page with that,you should be able to find a few decent ones. — maybe this is not what you need, but I thought I'd mention  [Page Layers](https://www.pagelayers.com/). It can export layered psd files and also in 2x size. It is kinda expensive though.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used a program called Paparazzi to take pictures of websites:
https://paparazzi.en.softonic.com/mac

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If the only solution is a separate browser tool, rather than the browser I'm already using, then I'll likely end up using PhantomJS or Puppeteer.